# How to handle null values in a JSON object that are converted to "null" strings on output?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have an AJAX call to retrieve a JSON encoded object ('result') that may contain some null values. When I use

```
 $.each(result, function(x,y) {
   y.myvalue + "<br/>";
 }
```

to output the values, any null value is converted to the string "null".

I am aware I can use a dateFilter callback function in my AJAX call to replace null values, but that seems expensive, unreliable and unnecessary.

I could also do something like:

```
 $.each(result, function(x,y) {
   (y.myvalue || "") + "<br/>";
   (y.myvalue ? y.myvalue: "") + "<br/>";
 }
```

But those mechanisms both seem messy.

What's the easiest, slickest, least expensive way of handling this?

I've read a few questions on this site with similar issues but I've yet to find a definitive answer.

Comment: The second example you use - `(y.myvalue || "") + "<br/>"` - is the slickest, easiest and least expensive way.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan but surely there must be a better solution. I have a ton of these functions, each with multiple values returned, that will need to be updated

Comment: You can prototype a method on the String object if you'd prefer, but I don't see the point. What's the issues with this solution? It's effectively the same as a null coalescing operator in any other language.

Comment: It's not necessarily ugly it just seems like a bit of a hack. Why would null values be converted to strings in the first place? It'll also be a real drag to go over all that old code and make so many ammendments

Comment: Not a hack in the slightest, as I mentioned it's equivalent to a null coalescing operator. Surely, whatever the solution, you'll need to amend your old code.

Comment: True, but if I could combine this into the dataFilter function somehow I'd just need to add one line. In that second example I'd have to ammend X number of lines per function.